# Freemarker & SuiteScript rendered Advanced PDF - Replace double hyphens within a field

Tags: netsuite, freemarker, suitescript2.0

I have a scenario where I have an XML advanced PDF template, and SuiteScript renders the PDF.

However, one of the fields on the record I'm working with, is a text area, and the user has entered -- (to hyphens) in the text.

The PDF when rendering doesn't like this, as -- renders as escape characters when the fields are embedded with BFO.

what I want to do, is dynamically replace this field

${item.customtextfield?replace("--","..","r") or something like that, and see if that gets around the issue.

A bit like replacing `&` with `&amp;` in URLs for images.

My regex knowledge is not very good within freemarker, so not sure if above is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen the rest of your code, but if your field is a custom body field, you probably need to access **record** instead of **item**.

This worked for me (in my case, custbody_textarea is a custom field on invoice record):

```
<#if record.custbody_textarea?has_content>
  ${record.custbody_textarea?replace("--", "..")}
</#if>
```

Comment: "r" just means that you are specifying a regular expression in the first parameter, not just simple text. Both with or without "r" all matches will be replaced.

Comment: Also you can get rid of the `#if` in simple cases. Just use `!` to default the expression to an empty string: `${record.custbody_textarea!?replace("--", "..")}`